# POST on WebUI works with firefox but leads to Error 400 with curl?

Tags: linux, curl

i need to reboot my Orbi (RBS50) router and satelites (RBS50) frequently (don't ask). Unfortunaly Netgear doesnt't offer ssh/telnet access anymore. So i need to use the webinterface.

When i'll do this in the browser everything is fine. I'll open the page, do the Basic auth, and push the button. So i did this in the firefox developer console and exported the curl command. Here is exactly how it works in a clean Browser (Firefox in Private-Mode) : [full HAR-Export of the Login and the Reboot-Request i](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ijkovyw44game8c/192.168.0.6_Reboot_With_trivialPW.har?dl=0)

Exportetd as Curl the two requests looks like this (Original from Firefox no edits):

1. Open the Reboot-Page with Basic Auth:

   curl 'https://192.168.0.6/reboot.htm' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1'
2. Press the "Yes" button to perform the Reboot

   curl 'https://192.168.0.6/apply.cgi?/reboot_waiting.htm%20timestamp=71222162842' -X POST -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Origin: https://192.168.0.6' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46UGFzc3dvcnQwMA==' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: [https://192.168.0.6/reboot.htm'](https://192.168.0.6/reboot.htm%27) -H 'Cookie: auth_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOiI4OTg3NiIsImlzcyI6Ind3dy5uZXRnZWFyLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6Ik1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChYMTE7IFVidW50dTsgTGludXggeDg2XzY0OyBydjoxMDkuMCkgR2Vja28vMjAxMDAxMDEgRmlyZWZveC8xMDkuMCJ9.2b3420f66ed35dd347c38e280f6b0ebedfd5ee2fdd5b3ab53384965fb241c6ba' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' --data-raw 'submit_flag=reboot&yes=Ja+'

Here is what I've done from it.

1. Curl the Reeboot-Page with Basic out works fine: The html is shown, the Cookie is written.

   curl --insecure -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt 'https://192.168.0.6/reboot.htm' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -u "admin:Passwort00"
2. Try to send the POST to perform the Reboot:

   curl --insecure -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt 'https://192.168.0.6/apply.cgi?/reboot_waiting.htm%20timestamp=71222162842' -X POST -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Origin: https://192.168.0.6' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46UGFzc3dvcnQwMA==' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: [https://192.168.0.6/reboot.htm'](https://192.168.0.6/reboot.htm%27) -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' --data-raw 'submit_flag=reboot&yes=Ja+'

The Answher:

`400 Bad Requestclasses.num.all.fontFamily = Courier; classes.num.all.fontSize = 10pt;

## 400 Ungültige Anforderung

Der vom Client angeforderte Vorgang wird vom Server nicht unterstützt.

`

I have absolute no idea why the reboot button works at Firefox, but not as a Curl.
I've tried lots of combination of all headers that are in the original request.

Comment: I see you have a same-origin header, is the firefox website fetching resources from the same domain? then it's not strange you can't curl it if it is configured to only accept requests from the same-origin (same website)

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. Both requests are copied from Firefox. I exported it from there as Curl, and only removed the "Authorization: Basic" and the "Cookie: auth_token". (And built in my own one instead. But the login doesn't seem to be the problem.)

So, i thougt it should work the same.

It also doesn't change anything if I remove the "Sec-Fetch-..." headers.

Comment: Is this fixed not variable `yes=Ja+` ? I'd expect there to be some kind of nonce / one-time-token in the POSTs to prevent replay attacks, but perhaps Netgear isn't clever enough to do that?

Comment: i bet you're missing a part of the LOGIN process. not exactly sure which part, but I'm positive. do you have php? what OS are you on? Mac? Windows?

Comment: yes, the value "yes=ja+" is fixed. But you're right, ther maybe was a kind of timestamp  in the URL parameter. I'll thought it has to do with the waitbar when the reeboot is done in the next step. I'll check that as soon I'll have some time.

Comment: There is no real login. Only basic Auth. You'll bring the username/password (and the login-cookie ) or not. If not/wrong, youl yust get unauthorized instead of the requested page.

Comment: @Benjamin- contact me on https://www.facebook.com/hanshenrik.bergan , i'm free all sunday

Comment: @hanshenrik Thanks for your offer. i've never been on Facebook, and last Sunday I also thought I'd get a handle on it myself with the hints here. But I didn't really get any further...

Comment: @Benjamin- how about Discord then? I'm `Takeoded#1532`

Comment: guess you're not on Discord either. did you figure it out? :P

Comment: Yes and no. 
I have had an Discord account some time ago. But the bigger Problem is, that i can hardly find time to stay at the Problem at the momment.
So i had to find an other solution. I bought some programmable power plugs that briefly cut the power once a night. Not an elegant solution, but one that works. :-(